# How to use bootstrap or css for never appear scrollbar

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, html-table, react-bootstrap

The question is in the title, on React Application, i want to never see the window scrollbar, i would like to the content never overflowing for each screen size.

```
      // App.js
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="site">
          <Navbar/>
          ...
          // some routes
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <footer></footer>

      //App.css
     * {
         box-sizing: border-box !important;
     }

    .site {
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -40px;
    }

    footer {
       height:40px;
       background-color:red;
    }
```

For example, i have a table, if content overflow, only scroll table appear but never this of window.

````
   <div style={{maxHeight:"70vh", overflowY:"auto"}}>
     <table>
     ...
     </table>
   </div>
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solved it, i wrapped my site in a div

```
// App.js
<div className="site">
  <Navbar/> //navbar component
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch> // from react router dom
      <Route/> // some many routes
   ...
</div>

// App.css
.site {
  height:100%
}
```

And after in component who contain my table

```
<Container style={{height:"calc(100% - 120px)", display:"flex", flexDirection:"column"}}>
  <div style={{overflowY:"auto"}}>
    <Table>
    ...
```

I hope so this answer can help another developers

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply do it with CSS like :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

If you can't with this, play with the overflow, for me it's the only answers.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent overflow you can disable overflow for body element.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

When hiding scrollbar you have to remember not only about chrome, but also firefox and safari.

Answer (score 0):

When i say never see the scrollbar, i would like just ajust the height property for each screen not only masked it.